# Why Is It That the Number of Subsets of a Set $S$ (the Cardinality of the Power Set of $S$) Is $2^{|S|}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why is it that the number of subsets of a set $S$ (the cardinality of the power set of $S$) is $2^{|S|}$?

I suspect that there is some sort of combinatorial argument for this fact?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please explain this.

Comment: For each element of $S$, you can either include it or not: that's 2 possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an argument with a "combinatorial flavor", which works for *finite* $\vert S \vert$:

We observe that the binomial theorem yields

$2^k = (1 + 1)^k = \displaystyle \sum_{r = 0}^k \dfrac{k!}{r! (k - r)!} 1^r 1^{k - r} = \sum_{r = 0}^k \dfrac{k!}{r! (k - r)!}; \tag 1$

but

$C^k_r = \dfrac{k!}{r! (k - r)!} \tag 2$

is precisely the number of [***combinations of $k$ things taken $r$ at at time***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination); that is, the number of ways we may choose $r$ elements from a set $S$ with $\vert S \vert = k$, irrespective of order; thus it is the number of $r$-element subsets of $S$.  It follows then that the sums occurring in (1) count all subsets of $S$, whence

$\vert P(S) \vert =  \displaystyle \sum_{r = 0}^k \dfrac{k!}{r! (k - r)!} = 2^k = 2^{\vert S \vert}, \tag 3$

as per request.

Comment: I went through this step-by-step to ensure that I understood it, and I found it to be a very enlightening experience. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @ThePointer:  Thank you sir for the kind words and for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that a subset $A$ of $S$ can be identified with a function $f$ from $S$ to a two element set, say $\{0,1\}$, with $f(x)=0$ if $x\not\in A$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\in A$...

Comment: Thanks for the response. This explanation is only half of the picture: there is no combinatorial argument, which is the other half.

Comment: The function space $X^Y$ has order $\mid X\mid ^{\mid Y\mid}$.

Answer (score 1):

We can construct any subset of $S$ by examining each element and deciding whether or not to put it in the subset. For each element we have two options: put it in the subset, or leave it out. Thus, there are $2^{|S|}$ options for subsets since $|S|$ is the number of elements we go through in our decision process.

Of course, we require $|S|<\infty$.

Comment: "Of course, we require |S|<∞"  Why "of course".  Surely wanting to know the cardinality of $P(\mathbb N)$ or of $P(\mathbb R)$ or the power sets of infinite sets is a valid question. And if they are *not* $2^{|\mathbb N|}$ or $2^{|\mathbb R|}$ then knowing that $|P(S)|=2^{|S|}$ for finite sets is practically useless if it doesn't tell us the cardinality of power sets of infinite sets.

Comment: @fleablood The OP asks for the number of subsets, so for $2^{|S|}$ to be a number we require $|S|<\infty$. Although I understand that we use the same notation and a similar argument is used when $S$ is infinite.

Comment: Well, that's true.  The op DID ask for "number".  But I interpreted it as a naive way of asking for cardinality which is an issue that will have to be dealt with eventually.  The notation $2^{|\mathbb N|}$ intuitively make sense as that would be the "number" of all possible binary sequences, which although I still say/and think naively even though it is not a number.  And that the cardinality is the same can use the same proof.  Less intuitive is $2^{\mathbb R}$ which would be all functions $\mathbb R\to \{0,1\}$ which... I guess isn't that less intuitive.

Comment: Hmm.... you know, a question I have never seen asked before:  Is there any set $S$ where $|P(S)| =\aleph_0= |\mathbb N|$.  I've never seen anyone ask that question.  It's kind of a good question for a student.

Comment: @fleablood:  Do you know the answer to what you just asked--if $\exists S \mid \vert P(S) \vert = \aleph_0 = \vert \Bbb N \vert$?  I'm curious about it now . . . Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I do.  And considering the we're discussing how $|P(S)| = 2^{|S|}$ you should too.  For what set is $2^{|S|} = \aleph_0$?